# Why are some functionalities inside a bigger function written as lambdas in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I was under the impression that writing crisp functions that does just one thing is better than writing a relatively larger function that does more than one thing and enclosing that as a lambda?

Comment: That's purely about opinion/style. I don't think there's much of an objective answer to get here.

Comment: The general advice is that you structure your code in a more modular fashion by writing functions which do self-contained things. You are correct in that regard. Nothing more can be said, it is merely an advice.

Comment: Lots of internal functions that are 2 lines long don't belong in public header files, but that is what you tend to get without lambdas. If your lambda is more than a couple of lines long consider making it a stand-alone function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When thinking about the length of a function, it's useful to consider the *body* of any lambdas inside it to be *not* part of the length. Imagine to yourself they have been extracted to elsewhere and just referenced.

Having said that, let's distinguish two cases of lambdas:

### Capturing lambdas

Virtually required to be defined in-function, as the alternative is creating a class type with an appropriate `operator()` and some initialiser. Values of such function types are not really useful outside of the function using them. This is both more boilerplate and less localised, there is *no* upside.

E.g. given

```
struct Compound
{
    int interesting_member;
    std::string uninteresting_member;
};
```

If you want to find a specific `Compound` in a `std::vector<Compound>` based on only the value of `interesting_member`, you can implement it either

```
struct CompoundFinder
{
    bool operator(const Compound & item) { return item.interesting_member == needle; }
    int needle;
}

std::vector<Compound>::iterator find_by_interesting(int needle, std::vector<Compound> & haystack)
{
    return std::find_if(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), CompoundFinder{ needle });
}
```

Or with a capturing lambda

```
std::vector<Compound>::iterator find_by_interesting(int needle, std::vector<Compound> & haystack)
{
    return std::find_if(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), 
        [needle](const Compound & item) 
        { return item.interesting_member == needle; });
}
```

### Non-Capturing lambdas

Here it is less clear cut. If you only need a particular function once, it can be simpler to definition a lambda rather than add a name to the enclosing scope that performs the same task.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often, especially in algorithms in a standard library, there's a need to provide a short function. Some of the obvious examples of that are super-short functions that "tell" the `std::sort` how to properly compare two values (say you are sorting a vector of your own type with multiple keys and you want to sort "this time" by one of those keys).

In these cases it used to be required (pre-C++11) to write that short function as a named function. Doing so would generally pollute the name space and to solve this - lambdas were introduced.

This doesn't violate the "one function - one thing" principle as the lambda in this case is just a supporting shortcut for an in-place short code that would otherwise need be put into a standalone named function.